# Exception: @error: Max Equation Length in Gekko

Tags: python, optimization, numpy-ndarray, gekko

I am doing a portfolio optimization using Gekko. I am using the returns per asset and its covariance matrix as input. The code I am trying is

```
# Initialize Model
m = GEKKO(remote=True)

#initialize variables
w=m.Array(m.Var,23)

for i in range(23):
    w[i].value = 0.04347826
    w[i].lower = 0.0
    w[i].upper = 1.0


#Equations
m.Equation(0.18 >= (np.dot(w.T,np.dot(covariance_ar, w)))**0.5)
m.Equation(np.sum(w[0:23]) == 1.0)
m.Equation(w[7]+w[9]+w[11] >= (np.sum(w[7:13])*0.3))
m.Equation(w[7]+w[9]+w[11] <= (np.sum(w[7:13])*0.7))
m.Equation(w[11]+w[12] >= 0.0)
m.Equation(w[11]+w[12] <= (np.sum(w[7:13])*0.15))


#Objective
m.Obj(-(np.sum(return_ar.T @ w)))

#Solve simulation
m.solve() # solve on public server

#Results
for i in range(23):
    print('w['+str(i)+']='+str(w[i].value))
```

return_ar is an array of returns of individual assets of shape (23,1) and covariance_ar is the covariance array of returns of shape (23,23)

Although the code ran succesfully with small number of weights, with 23 weight parameters it is throwing error
Exception:  @error: Max Equation Length.......
APM model error: string >       15000  characters
Consider breaking up the line into multiple equations

Can you help me to formulate the code constraint so that this works.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't run your code because it was missing values so I had to modify it with sample values.

```py
# Initialize Model
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO(remote=True)

#initialize variables
w=m.Array(m.Var,23)

for i in range(23):
    w[i].value = 0.04347826
    w[i].lower = 0.0
    w[i].upper = 1.0

#Equations
covariance_ar = np.random.rand(23,23)
m.Equation(0.18 >= (np.dot(w.T,np.dot(covariance_ar, w)))**0.5)
m.Equation(m.sum(w[0:23]) == 1.0)
m.Equation(w[7]+w[9]+w[11] >= (m.sum(w[7:13])*0.3))
m.Equation(w[7]+w[9]+w[11] <= (m.sum(w[7:13])*0.7))
m.Equation(w[11]+w[12] >= 0.0)
m.Equation(w[11]+w[12] <= (m.sum(w[7:13])*0.15))

#Objective
m.Obj(-(m.sum(w)))

#Solve simulation
m.solve() # solve on public server

#Results
for i in range(23):
    print('w['+str(i)+']='+str(w[i].value))
```

This reproduces the same error that you observed. You can overcome the equation length limitation by redefining your `np.dot` functions with list comprehensions. Also, you need to use the `m.sum()` gekko function instead of the numpy function for summation.

```py
# Initialize Model
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO(remote=True)

#initialize variables
w=m.Array(m.Var,23)

for i in range(23):
    w[i].value = 0.04347826
    w[i].lower = 0.0
    w[i].upper = 1.0

#Equations
C = np.random.rand(23,23)
Cw = [m.sum([m.Intermediate(C[i,j]*w[j]) \
             for j in range(23)]) \
                 for i in range(23)]
wCw = m.sum([Cw[i]*w[i] for i in range(23)])
m.Equation(0.18 >= (wCw)**0.5)
m.Equation(m.sum(w[0:23]) == 1.0)
m.Equation(w[7]+w[9]+w[11] >= (m.sum(w[7:13])*0.3))
m.Equation(w[7]+w[9]+w[11] <= (m.sum(w[7:13])*0.7))
m.Equation(w[11]+w[12] >= 0.0)
m.Equation(w[11]+w[12] <= (m.sum(w[7:13])*0.15))

#Objective
return_ar = np.ones(23)
for i in range(23):
    m.Maximize(w[i]*return_ar[i])

#Solve optimization
m.solve() # solve on public server

#Results
for i in range(23):
    print('w['+str(i)+']='+str(w[i].value))
```

You can now use your values for `covariance_ar` and `return_ar`. The reason this method works is that Gekko can break down the equations into smaller pieces that are solved individually. The length limitation for each equation of 15,000 characters is not just a processing limitation but also encourages better model formulation strategies that work well with sparse nonlinear programming solvers.

Comment: Thank you John for your reply. However running the code you shared is also giving me an error Creating file: infeasibilities.txt
 Use command apm_get(server,app,'infeasibilities.txt') to retrieve file
 @error: Solution Not Found
The same set of equations is giving valid result in other packages so can you please help with the Gekko.

Comment: The code I provided uses random numbers for your matrices so some of the combinations may be infeasible. Are you using your updated matrices?

Comment: I tried using the random matrices as well as the updated matrices. Both are giving the same error. Thanks.

Comment: One thing to try is to comment out the inequality constraints until the problem becomes feasible. This can help you identify which one is creating the infeasibility. Also, you can try switching to a different solver with `m.options.SOLVER=1`. I got a successful solution but maybe my random numbers were different than yours. Could you post a link to your matrices or a complete script if you still need help?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried the solver but it isn't working. And by commenting out the constraints I found the CWC part is creating the infeasibility. The link to this project   https://www.kaggle.com/sutanuka/optimization-with-gekko

Comment: John I am getting an error while running the code you provided. The solution is not provided due to an issue around m.Intermediate equation. Will you be able to help.

Comment: The exception is because a solution is not found. There is no error with the code and the solver is returning the correct solution that there is no solution to the given constraints. I recommend that you eliminate constraints or simplify until the problem becomes feasible. Then you can add constraints to see which one makes it infeasible.

Comment: Even with a simplified version - where C = np.random.rand(5,5), return_ar = np.ones(5) and w = m.Array(m.Var,5) is providing the solution error. Introducing the m.intermediate set of equation in place of np.dot(w.T,np.dot(cov_test_ar, w)))**0.5 is creating this issue.

Comment: One thing that you can do is square both sides of the constraint such as `m.Equation(0.18 >= (wCw)**0.5)` becomes `m.Equation(0.18**2 >= wCw)`. Does this help?